# Powerbuilder saveas xlsx, after 170000 rows it's not working, returns -1 or crashes

Tags: excel, powerbuilder, save-as, datawindow

I have an issue when using DataWindow `SaveAs` function. Previously the function was working with Excel8 format and the rowcount didn't exceeded 65536. But now there could be 300000 or more rows in the DW that needs to be exported.

I've changed the `SaveAs` format to XLSX!, I've successfully saved 170000 rows with 66 columns.

But it didn't saved the 180000 or bigger rowcount DW-s. Sometimes it crashed or just returned -1. But after that I was able to export smaller dw-s only if I restarted Powerbuilder.

This machine is using Windows 8, has 16GB of RAM, and has office installed, and I'm using Powerbuilder version 12.5.2.

I've made a small test program on a different machine with Windows 7 and 3GB of RAM, plus Powerbuilder 12.5. I've succesfully saved a DW in .xlsx format which had 990000 rows and 15 columns, although I added another column and it crashed again.

I've read the limitations of Excel, but they seem okay with what I've been trying to save.

Any idea what to check or what to do in the above situation?

Comment: I can't help but can confirm the behavior.  I just wrote it off to memory problems with Excel-- I don't believe it has anything to do with PB but anything is possible.  Maybe experiment with columns, formats to try and find some combination that is less memory intensive. Also maybe try on a machine with newer version of Excel just to see what happens. I believe that we made a work-around by saving into two spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem but esist way to overcome this situation is as below:

1. Save the dw data to a csv file in which case you won't have that rowcount limitation.
2. Then open an OLE oblect and connect to excel.
3. Open the saved csv in OLE.
4. Next step is to save as the ole excel to your installed excel format i.e. xls or xlsx.

Hope this will help.